# Saving html form into a txt file and then reading txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have the following html form so far:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jn9p7meL/
```

```
<form>
    <p>
        <label>Tenant Name:</label> 
        <input type="text"> <span class="remove">Remove</span><br>
        <label>Tenant URL:</label> <input type="text"><br>
        <label>API Token:</label> <input type="text"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="aws" name="aws" value="AWS">
        <label for="aws"> AWS</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="azure" name="azure" value="Azure">
        <label for="azure"> Azure</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="paas" name="paas" value="PaaS">
        <label for="paas"> PaaS</label><br><br>
        
    </p>
    <p>
        <br><span class="add">Add fields</span>
    </p>
</form>
<script>
$(".add").click(function() {
    $("form > p:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-child");
    return false;
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
</script>
```

This is a configuration file where I will use the values created by the end user to run a script.

When users finish filling in the form, I want to have a submit button that saves their inputs into a text file (config.txt).

E.g

```
[Tenant 1]
TenantName= test1
TenantURL= www.test1.com
TenantToken= token1
AWS= 0
Azure= 1
PaaS= 0

[Tenant 2]
TenantName= test2
TenantURL= www.test2.com
TenantToken= token2
AWS= 1
Azure= 1
PaaS= 0
```

- Users can input more than one tenant information, press 'add fields' on jsfiddle.net.

Once I have a file created I want there to be a check to see if config.txt exists. If so it reads the file and creates the form based on current input. Users can then overwrite rather then create a new config.txt

Is this possible?

I have no idea how to now make my form create a file and once the file is created to read it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes it's possible. Add a submit button. Have your PHP form receiver format the string with your intended syntax. Then `file_put_contents('config.txt', $data);` to write it in. Use `file_exists('config.txt');` to check if the file exists. Use `file_get_contents('config.txt');` to read the file. The manual is your friend: Study [filesystem functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php). Other than that, your life may be easier if you serialize the array/data you have as JSON (`json_encode/json_decode)` rather than ini-file style.

Comment: Hi Markus, thats great to hear it possible! I think i need to practice with html a bit more to fully understand how to implement this.

Comment: it seems to me like you need practice with PHP basics rather than HTML.